# Missing mocinclude.tmp

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt4, mingw

I'm porting an Qt4.8.5, mingw 3.5 app to mingw 4.8.2, that is already correctly working on Linux gcc 4.8.2. What I'm getting is:

> mingw32-make[]: ***No rule to make target 'moc-release/mocinclude.tmp'
>   needed by 'moc-release/moc_main.cpp'

In MakeFile I see:

```
check: first

./moc-rel//mocinclude.tmp:
        @echo -IC:\Qt\4.8.6\include/QtCore> ./moc-rel//mocinclude.tmp
         @echo -IC:\Qt\4.8.6\include/QtNetwork>> ./moc-rel//mocinclude.tmp
         @echo -IC:\Qt\4.8.6\include/QtGui>> ./moc-rel//mocinclude.tmp
         @echo -IC:\Qt\4.8.6\include/QtXml>> ./moc-rel//mocinclude.tmp
         @echo -IC:\Qt\4.8.6\include>> ./moc-rel//mocinclude.tmp
         ...
```

When I create that file empty by hand the app compiles fine. I know that my include path is quite long, but it should be fine anyway, right? Am I missing something, or should I just add this file to git to have it in place?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your makefile, you have this rule:

```
./moc-rel//mocinclude.tmp:
        @echo -IC:\Qt\4.8.6\include/QtCore> ./moc-rel//mocinclude.tmp
        ...
```

Notice that it will build the file `./moc-rel/mocinclude.tmp`, which is *not* the same as `./moc-release/mocinclude.tmp`. You appear to have a dependency, elsewhere in the makefile, on the latter, but only the rule to build the former. You need to resolve this discrepancy.

Comment: I see your point and it's possible workaround. However my Makefile is created by qmake from Qt. It looks like a compiler and qt version bug.

Comment: @LiborTomsik: well, if qmake is creating invalid makefiles, that's an issue you need to raise with its maintainers; SO is hardly an appropriate forum for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `#` before `MOC_DIR` to commented it out.
Then compile will be done.